# Android webview - javascript not working for OS < 2.3

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-2.2-froyo

I have an application that uses a webview to call functions via javascript.  Everything is gravy for Android OS 2.3 and higher, but there is a silent failure on anything 2.2 or below.  My webview code is pasted below, and in the javascript file I have a simple callback for:

```
<body onLoad='onLoad()'>
```

that never gets triggered.  Any ideas on what could be wrong?

```
        mMessageView = new WebView(main);
        clearWebviewCache();
        WebSettings mSettings = mMessageView.getSettings();
        mSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mMessageView.addJavascriptInterface(new DriverInterface(main), "messageView");              
        mMessageView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
            {
                log("load progress = " + progress);

            }
        });
```